# Can I save my financial aid after this?

Tags: gpa, community-college

During fall 2021, I took 3 classes at my community college. I had very good financial aid so nearly everything was paid for. My first issue was in my online nutrition class. I took a hit when I submitted an “incorrect form” of document on my final so I guess when the professor tried to open it he was unable to see my work. So he gave me a 0 on the final. I reached out to him and asked if I could put my work on a different document and resubmit for a correction, and he said yes. I did it immediately and resubmitted it, but he never actually corrected it. So I ended with B’s in my other 2 classes, but I got a D in his class.

My second issue was also in an online psychology class (spring 22). The professor dropped me without notice. To this day I’m really not sure what the issue was, it was about a week into the semester and there were no meetings I could have missed, etc.

I feel that because of these 2 events my gpa/aid has been affected, is there anyone I can talk to to avoid taking a big hit? I just feel kind of powerless as the nutrition professor really didn’t have to correct my final, but he said he would and he didn’t. And I thought it was strange for my psychology professor to drop me without notice.

Comment: The rules for financial aid are almost certainly local. You will have to ask at the college. The financial aid office might be a place to start. Or the department head.

Comment: Probably too late now, but did you follow up with either professor, to remind the former of his agreement or to ask the latter why they dropped you?

Answer (score 1):

> he never actually corrected it

Ask him again, politely.  He was likely very busy and not paid anything for the extra work you are asking him to do.

> The professor dropped me without notice ... about a week into the semester

If you were removed from the course a week into the semester, it should not appear in your record or have anything to do with your financial aid.

That said, the word "dropped" is quite vague.

For some financial aid, the college can decide what it wants to do.  For other aid, there are fixed rules we do not know, but you can ask them to give you the rules.

Comment: Sometimes financial aid is dependent on completing some number of credits, so a dropped course (for any reason) can certainly be relevant. Of course I don't know what's relevant to OP specifically because they don't provide enough information.